# c# static class field and parameter with same name

Tags: c#, static

As `this.name` is not working to access fields with the same name like a method parameter in static classes, I'm looking for a way to do so.

As an example i would like to do this:

```
static class test
{
    private static string aString;
    public static void method(string aString)
    {
        // aString (field) = aString (parameter)
    }
}
```

Comment: A better option would be to rename the *parameter* to `astring`. The convention is that parameters start with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use:

```
test.Astring = x;
```

i.e. replace *this* with the class name, *test* in this case.

Comment: It's *far* better to rename the parameter to `aString`. Otherwise the very next question will be "why can't I modify my static field?"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i agree

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't name variables like that ;) I just typed in anything

Comment: @Mr.Toast: That is a problem in itself. The more conventional and realistic you make your examples, the better we'll be able to help you. Don't forget that the main purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high-quality questions and answers. Spend time crafting your question rather than just "typing in anything".

Comment: @Mr.Toast: But the class name is still unconventional too... as is the method name. And even `aString` would be a lousy parameter name. I'd use `Test`, `Method` and `value` as more reasonable names. It's all a matter of thinking about the long term life of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
static class test
{
    private static string Astring="static";
    public static void method(string Astring)
    {
        string passedString = Astring; // will be the passed value
        string staticField = test.Astring; //  will be static  
    }
}
```

if we call the method like `test.method("Parameter");` the `staticField` will have the value  `static` and  `passedString` will have the value  `Parameter`.

> The keyword `this` denotes the current instance of the class; static
>   fields cannot be accessed through instance you should use the class
>   name instead for accessing the static field.

Note :-  But please take care while [naming the variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx). Avoid giving same name in same class. It will be best if you define the class like the following

```
static class test
    {
        private static string StaticAstring="static";
        public static void method(string passedAstring)
        {
            string staticField = StaticAstring; // will be static 
            string passedString = passedAstring; // will be the passed value  
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've named your local variables the wrong round at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet :  thanks for mentioning, I have corrected that